# How can I drive one speaker with a stereo signal?

Tags: audio

I’m building a small Bluetooth speaker based on a board (DW-CT14+) that outputs two amplified audio signals (left and right stereo channels). I only have room for one speaker in my device so I need to combine these into one mono signal. How is this done?

---

I tried wiring both outputs to the speaker through a pair of resistors, as many articles suggest. I tried 100 ohm resistors first but the sound was too low. I switched to 10 ohm, and the sound is loud enough, but every few seconds the sound glitches and the whole board seems to reset. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Normally Mono is done by mixing , or adding 2 equal resistors in the preamp that are a value that wont be loaded by the preamp high input impedance nor too low that it loads the source.  One for the same cut path and one from the other channel.  That's the general idea.

Comment: It depends how the module works. If there is a separate amp chip, you need to sum the L+R signal before the amp. After the amp it is not feasible to sum it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tweak my stereo bluetooth amplifier into mono](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/600816/how-to-tweak-my-stereo-bluetooth-amplifier-into-mono)

Comment: It’s one board that produces an amplified stereo output. There is no input. My only option is to sum the output.

Comment: How about the software? You could simply change your audio player app (VLC?) to output the audio in mono. No re-wiring necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The DW-CT14+ is an amplifier board. It has bridged outputs for the speakers.

A cheap'n'cheerful way to get a mono output is to drive your single speaker bridged between the R+ and L- outputs. This will sum the two audio signals in phase to give the correct mono signal.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This almost works. I can hear both channels but there is a high pitched whine that can be heard whenever there is silence or low volume in the audio. The whine is not present if I only connect one channel.

Comment: That whine is probably the class-D switching pulses, from each amplifier's output, beating against one another.  The switching pulses frequency are above our range of hearing, not exactly equal to one another, and are not synchronized. While they are too high for us to hear, the beat frequency is in the audible range.  This is all telling us  that "this idea is a bad idea".  You cannot connect the outputs of these amplifiers together.

Answer (score 0):

There are two NS4165 amplifiers on the board. Their input pins (pin 4) connected to bluetooth receiver via capacitors and 22k resistors in series. I circled the resistor-capacitor pairs and highlighted two traces in the image below. (original image is from [this amazon listing](https://www.amazon.in/Icstation-Bluetooth-Stereo-Audio-Amplifier/dp/B0796TJ9FT))

[image]

While IC pins and traces are rather hard to hack, you can use resistor and capacitor pads to mix two channels together between the bluetooth receiver and amplifiers. All you need is two small 22k through-hole resistors and then you can use either channel to drive your speaker. Of course, if you don't need second channel then one resistor is enough.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately there's no way I could do this physically, I haven't got the tools, the parts, or the skills.

Comment: I'd also really like to understand why I can't just do this to the output of the amplifiers instead of the input signal.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't simply short the outputs of these IC's. The audio outputs of all these IC are low-impedance voltage sources. If you short together low-impedance voltage sources, you will get unpredictable results, and possible damage the ICs.  Using some 'ballast' resistors to mix the two outputs, as you first did, could  "work". The resistors need to be high-enough resistance that does not destabilize the IC operation. You stated you did get it to "work" with 100-ohm resistors. Maybe 47-ohms would work?

Comment: Actually that wont work. These amplfier ICs on this board are not designed to have their outputs paralleled.

Comment: I assume they are set to operate as class-D switching amplifiers - where the audio signal is 'running' on top of a very high frequency pulses. The speaker outputs are floating, and do not have a common 'ground' between the 2 ICs. Lastly, the two amplifiers are not synchronized to one another, the pulses are switching independently and could counteract one another, i.e., form a short circuit.

Comment: So, the ballast resistors relieve the 'short circuit' condition, or heavy loading, but you probably still get that "beating" whine sound.

Comment: @Flarosa "I haven't got the tools, the parts, or the skills" sorry to hear that. Maybe this site cannot help you, as most answers usually presume at least some basic soldering skills. And your specific device needs a bit of rework to function properly.

Comment: Is there another board I could start with that would be easier to adapt?

Comment: @FrankLaRosa Maybe, but I am not familiar with any. All those I've seen have the same basic design - bluetooth receiver with stereo output that feeds into either two separate power amplifiers, or one dual-channel power amplifier. Maybe you can find some that can work in bridged mode, as Neil_UK suggested in his answer. But most likely you'd need to mix channels between receiver and amplifiers. At least this board provides easy access to do this. Just two common cheap parts soldered to four spots. You may know somebody who can solder them for you.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is contingent on having the correct tools and a few extra chip resistors. To work with these tiny parts, you need some fine tweezers, a soldering iron with extra fine tip (or the special 2-print tip), some flux, and either a 10x to 20x magnifying glass or microscope with good illumination.  For this task, in particular, you need 2 extra chip resistors. The resistors should be the same size as those used on the PC board. Their resistance value is not critical, as long as they are both the same. Their value could be in the range, like, 4.7K to 33K. In my image, I use the same value (22K) as is already used in the PC board. You also need a short piece of jumper wire, like #30 gauge or thinner.

Step 0: As it looks before any mods:

[image: unmodified circuit]

Step 1: Remove the 22K resistors (2 places). Must be careful, use the tweezers and the soldering iron.
[image: removing resistors]

Step 2: For a resistor "tent", made up of one of the removed 22K resistors and one of your extra resistors. Form a 45-degree angle with the 2 resistors. Solder this "tent" in place of the original resistor. Use some flux to make the joint quickly. If you take too long soldering, the heat will melt the 45-degree angle (and you'll have to start over).
[image: new resistors]

Step 3: Add the jumper wire, solder each end to the top of each "tent". Use flux to make it solder quickly. Be very quick! If you solder too long, it will collapse your tent.
[image: add jumper wire]

Option: Instead of a simple jumper wire, you could wire each "tent" connection to a switch (SPST). So you could switch this "mono" mode on & off.

Comment: very strange approach. can you draw a resulting schematics and explain why?